# Algorithm / MySQL - Get all points within a radius

Tags: mysql, algorithm

I have MySQL table of coordinates (longitude and latitude).

I would like to find the most efficient way to get all points around a certain point within a specific radius.

In other words,
input: longitude, latitude, radius (in kilometers)
output: all points (longitude and latitude) in this circle

How to do it in the most efficient way?

Comment: this might help you http://zcentric.com/2010/03/11/calculate-distance-in-mysql-with-latitude-and-longitude/

Comment: the most efficient way is not to be accurate and find a square instead of a circle, that way you don't need to calculate square roots and can just use simple range values

Answer (score 0):

One efficient way to do it, following @jean's idea, is to perform a range query then filter the points within the circle, since range query can be optimized by range index. Let (x, y, r) be the input. Namely,

```
SELETE * FROM coordinates WHERE longitude <= x + r and longitude >= x - r and latitude <= y + r and latitude >= y - r
```

Then you can load the tuples to memory and filter the result yourseft, or you do another sql query over the result of this subquery to filter the points.

Following the same idea, we can do it in a more fancy way: we can decompose the circle into multiple rectangles and perform range queries for all these rectangles, but I doubt how much this can improve the performance.